# Getting issue of Network Main Thread and Null Pointer exception

Tags: android, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception, networkonmainthread

```
package com.Itattooz.Gallery;
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class grid_layout extends Activity {

private GridView list;
private String id_folder;
private LazyAdapter1 adapter;
private Intent intent;
private String main_folder;
private JSONArray jArray;
private String result = null;
private InputStream is = null;
private StringBuilder sb = null;
private String[] r;
boolean flag1 = false, flag2 = false, flag3 = false;
private String[] sub_folder_id;
private String[] path;
private String[] sub_folder_name;
private String[] flag;
private String previouse_folder;
private String[] url;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.grid_layout);
    intent = getIntent();
    main_folder = intent.getStringExtra("selected_item");

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            databaseConnectivity();
        }
    }).start();


    list = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new LazyAdapter1(this, url, sub_folder_name);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(grid_listener);

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    list.setAdapter(null);
    super.onDestroy();
}

// djhwawd

OnItemClickListener grid_listener = new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
            long id) {
        id_folder = sub_folder_id[position];
        flag1 = true;

        TextView text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text);
        String str = (String) text.getText();
        if (flag[position].equals("X")) {

            //main_folder = main_folder + "/" + str.replace(" ", "%20");
            // int flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP;
            intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), grid_layout_main.class);
            intent.putExtra("folder_name",  main_folder.replace(" ", "%20") + "/" + str.replace(" ", "%20"));
            intent.putExtra("id", sub_folder_id[position]);

            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            flag2=true;
            main_folder = main_folder + "/" + str.replace(" ", "%20");
            int flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP;
            intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), grid_layout.class);
            intent.setFlags(flags);
            intent.putExtra("selected_item", main_folder);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }
};

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    setIntent(intent);

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            databaseConnectivity();
        }
    }).start();

    adapter = new LazyAdapter1(this, url, sub_folder_name);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.imageLoader.clearCache();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    list.setOnItemClickListener(grid_listener);

}

public void databaseConnectivity() {
    HttpPost httppost = null;
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    try {

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        if (flag1 == false) {
            nameValuePairs
            .add(new BasicNameValuePair("folder", main_folder));
            httppost = new HttpPost(
                    "http://www.itattooz.com/android/index.php");
        } else if (flag1 == true) {
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sub_folder_id",
                    id_folder));
            httppost = new HttpPost(
                    "http://www.itattooz.com/android/index2.php");
        }

        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        is = entity.getContent();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection" + e.toString());

    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();

        result = sb.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }
    String rt;
    try {
        jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        path = new String[jArray.length()];
        sub_folder_id = new String[jArray.length()];
        sub_folder_name = new String[jArray.length()];
        flag = new String[jArray.length()];
        url = new String[jArray.length()];
        JSONObject json_data = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            sub_folder_id[i] = json_data.getString("id");
            sub_folder_name[i] = json_data.getString("folder");
            flag[i] = json_data.getString("flag");
            path[i] = json_data.getString("path");

            rt = "http://www.itattooz.com/itattooz/"
                    + main_folder.replace(" ", "%20") + "/"
                    + sub_folder_name[i].replace(" ", "%20")
                    + "/cover_image/" + path[i].replace(" ", "%20");

            url[i] = rt;
        }
    } catch (JSONException e1) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Image Found",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (ParseException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

}
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
        onResume();
        Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "back button pressed");

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
@Override
public void onResume() { // After a pause OR at startup
    super.onResume();

    // Refresh your stuff here
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {

    super.onPause();
}
```

}

---

Hello Above is my code for a Gallery view as a grid layout ..

I researched a lot on net and got to know I should use AsyncTask for what I am trying to achieve .. Here Are few problems i am facing

1. I am doing something on Main thread
2. I want to change it to AsyncTask..

Don't know what should I do exactly to get rid of this issue.. Please Help...

Comment: using a thread is fine but if you get `NetworkOnMainThreadException` it means you are running network related operation on the ui thread.

Comment: it seams like you're not getting how threads are working ... Thread.start is not blocking so fx `url` in `adapter = new LazyAdapter1(this, url, sub_folder_name);` may or may be not null

Comment: a stacktrace would help us find the cause.

Answer (score 0):

use the `asyncTask` to handle this exception.

Please see the android developer [Link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

or you can see the stackoverflow Accepted answer related to this [Link HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

For exmp

```
 class YourTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, String> {
     protected String doInBackground(URL... urls) {
         // Fetch Data (Task A)
         return "Result";
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         // Show progress
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
         // Show UI after complete (Task B)
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Async Task

or

```
   if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9)  {  
   StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new  StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();    
   StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use              **AsyncTask**

or

add below code in your onCreate() method before thread starts to disable the strict mode using following code:

this is not the solution but avoids network IO on main thread so i recommend  **AsyncTask**

```
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }
```

also check internet permission in AndroidManifest.xml file

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```